# Convert sublists to dictionary

Tags: python

I currently have these sublists:

```
[['jjj', '3', 'bbb', '0', 'ddd', '9', 'ggg', '8', 'hhh', '2'],
 ['ccc', '2', 'ddd', '0', 'aaa', '3', 'hhh', '9'],
 ['ddd', '2', 'ggg', '5', 'ccc', '6', 'jjj', '1'],
 ['hhh', '9', 'iii', '5', 'eee', '7', 'bbb', '1'],
 ['iii', '6', 'ddd', '5', 'eee', '4', 'jjj', '3']]
```

What I would like to do is to convert these lists in a single dictionary with specific values per each key inside a list

e.g

```
{'jjj': ['3','1','3'],
 'bbb': ['0','1'],
 'ddd': ['9','0','2,'5']}
```

Comment: Where do you plann on getting those specific values from? The example ones you gave seem to exist in the sublists but is there any pattern to why you are using them?

Comment: I need to extract  letters as keys and numbers as values

Comment: Ok, but how are you deciding which key the value should fall under? Like, why `'jjj': ['3', '1', '3']` and not `['0','1']`?

Comment: I think she intends for the keys and value to be alternating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import collections

D=collections.defaultdict(list)

for sublist in main_list:
    for k in range(len(sublist)//2):
        D[sublist[2*k]].append(sublist[2*k+1])
```

Or, if you just want to use a simple dictionary:

```
D=dict()

for sublist in main_list:
    for k in range(len(sublist)//2):
        key=sublist[2*k]
        value=sublist[2*k+1]
        current=D.get(key)
        if current is None:
            D[key]=[value]
        else:
            current.append(value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a simple loop to go through the nested list and create a dictionary based on the key values. Here's how you can do it.

```
x = [['jjj', '3', 'bbb', '0', 'ddd', '9', 'ggg', '8', 'hhh', '2'],
     ['ccc', '2', 'ddd', '0', 'aaa', '3', 'hhh', '9'],
     ['ddd', '2', 'ggg', '5', 'ccc', '6', 'jjj', '1'],
     ['hhh', '9', 'iii', '5', 'eee', '7', 'bbb', '1'],
     ['iii', '6', 'ddd', '5', 'eee', '4', 'jjj', '3']]

y = {}
for i in x:
    for j in range (0, len(i),2):
        if i[j] in y.keys(): #if key already exists, add to list
            y[i[j]].append(i[j+1])
        else: #if key does not exist, create a list
            y[i[j]] = list(i[j+1])
print (y)
```

**Your output will be :**

```
{'jjj': ['3', '1', '3'], 'bbb': ['0', '1'], 'ddd': ['9', '0', '2', '5'], 'ggg': ['8', '5'], 'hhh': ['2', '9', '9'], 'ccc': ['2', '6'], 'aaa': ['3'], 'iii': ['5', '6'], 'eee': ['7', '4']}
```